# How to do an SQL request using CASE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do an `SQL request` using a clause `case`, but always it return this error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "CASE"
```

My request is the following:

```
SELECT distinct extract(month from "Facturation") as month, "LRU", "Client"

from "foundry_sync"."data"

    CASE month
  WHEN "month" =1 THEN 
    select avg("Montant_fac_eur") as c1 where "Facturation" between 1 and 6

 when "month" =2 THEN 
 select avg("Montant_fac_eur") as c2 where "Facturation" between 2 and 7

 when "month" =3 THEN
 select avg("Montant_fac_eur") as c3 where "Facturation" between 3 and 8

 when "month" = 4 then 
 select avg("Montant_fac_eur") as c4 where "Facturation" between 4 and 9

 when "month"=5 THEN
 select avg("Montant_fac_eur") as c5 where "Facturation" between 5 and 10

 when "month"=6 THEN 
 select avg("Montant_fac_eur") as c6 where "Facturation" between 6 and 11

 when "month"=7 THEN
 select avg("Montant_fac_eur") as c7 where "Facturation" between 7 and 11

 else ''

END 

group by "LRU", "Client", "Facturation"
order by "Client", "month"
```

I'm using `MySQL`.
`Facturation` is a `date`.

Can someone please tell me me where's my fault ?
Thank you.

Comment: This needs to happen before the `from` clause, not after it.

Comment: And neither your GROUP BY nor your ORDER BY clauses make any sense right now - because you used _text literals_ there, instead of actual _column names_. (Same for the CASEs as well.)

Comment: Try using Cursor. It would be perfect for your case

Comment: It makes no sense to use `SELECT DISTINCT` when you're using `GROUP BY`. The grouping already ensures that every row will be distinct.

Comment: There's no `FROM tablename` in the `SELECT avg()` subqueries.

Comment: All your double quotes are wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: And you mixed the two syntaxes of case expression with each other

Comment: @Shadow I don't mixed any thing I took the syntaxe from the official site of Mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: It looks like `Facturation` is a `DATETIME` or `DATE`. What is `Facturation BETWEEN 1 AND 6` supposed to mean?

Comment: @vero yes, you are mixing up the 2 syntaxes of case, see Barmar's anser below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many things wrong, it's hard to know where to begin.

You're mixing up the two forms of `CASE` expression. One form is:

```
CASE <expression>
    WHEN <value> THEN <result>
    WHEN <value> THEN <result>
    ...
END
```

the other is:

```
CASE
    WHEN <condition> THEN <result>
    WHEN <condition> THEN <result>
    ...
END
```

You're trying to use a `SELECT` query as a value, but it's missing the `FROM` clause and you have to wrap a query in parentheses to use it as a value. I suspect you wanted this to be querying from the same table, in which case you shouldn't be doing a subquery, you should just use the aggregation function in the main query.

The `CASE` expression should be part of the `SELECT` list, not after the `FROM` clause.

If you want to create separate columns in the output for each case, they can't be in one `CASE` expression.

You have all your table and column names in double quotes, MySQL uses backticks to quote names.

You don't need `SELECT DISTINCT` when using `GROUP BY`.

You can't refer to an alias in the `SELECT` list in the same query, except in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and `HAVING`.

It should be:

```
SELECT MONTH(Facturation) AS month, LRU, Client,
    AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(Factuation) = 1 AND Facturation BETWEEN 1 AND 6
        THEN Montant_fac_eur END) AS c1,
    AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(Factuation) = 2 AND Facturation BETWEEN 2 AND 7
        THEN Montant_fac_eur END) AS c2,
    AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(Factuation) = 3 AND Facturation BETWEEN 3 AND 8
        THEN Montant_fac_eur END) AS c3,
    AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(Factuation) = 4 AND Facturation BETWEEN 4 AND 9
        THEN Montant_fac_eur END) AS c4,
    ...
FROM foundry_sync.data
GROUP BY `LRU`, `Client`, `Facturation`
ORDER BY Client, month
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set the CASE before the FROM. I have taken off all the ", and you need brakets for every select statement after the where's, I would take off the GROUP BY and the ORDER BY clause too. And as someone said, you need a FROM clause in every select

```
SELECT distinct extract(month from Facturation) as month, LRU, Client,
    CASE month
  WHEN month =1 THEN 
    (select avg(Montant_fac_eur) as c1 where Facturation between 1 and 6)

 when month =2 THEN 
    (select avg(Montant_fac_eur) as c2 where Facturation between 2 and 7)

 when month =3 THEN
    (select avg(Montant_fac_eur) as c3 where Facturation between 3 and 8)

 when month = 4 then 
    (select avg(Montant_fac_eur) as c4 where Facturation between 4 and 9)

 when month=5 THEN
    (select avg(Montant_fac_eur) as c5 where Facturation between 5 and 10)

 when month=6 THEN 
    (select avg(Montant_fac_eur) as c6 where Facturation between 6 and 11)

 when month=7 THEN
    (select avg(Montant_fac_eur) as c7 where Facturation between 7 and 11)

 else ''

END 

from foundry_sync.data
group by LRU, Client, Facturation
order by Client, month
```